# Render R plots into markdown for Pandoc/Hakyll

Tags: r, haskell, markdown, pandoc, hakyll

How to integrate R code in markdown and then insert the plots in the rendered document?

I use the blogging engine Hakyll (http://jaspervdj.be/hakyll/).
It uses Pandoc as a back-end for rendering blog posts written in markdown.

Answer (score 1):

There's even a special markdown flavor named [R-markdown](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/). It can be rendered to plain markdown using the `knitr` package.

Apparently the link provided directs to a page about R-markdown V2 which has its own package `rmarkdown`.

Comment: I know about R-markdown, but how to render it in Hakyll? If I understand it's a preprocessor of plain markdown? Can it be plugged to Pandoc?

Comment: @cdupont You will have to use R at one point or the other to create the plots. Why not use R-markdown as it is intended? Judging from the main-page of Hakyll you can simply create a new compile rule to run `*.Rmd` files through R. before feeding the result to pandoc.

Comment: @ziggystart Great, I'll try that! If that works I 'll post the code.

Comment: @cdupont I don't understand your edit. You don't `require` `rmarkdown` for using the `knit` command. It provides the `rmarkdown::render` function, why do you load both packages when using only `knit`?

Comment: @ziggystart: OK, I didn't know. I wanted to add a method for use with Hakyll.

Answer (score 1):

FYI I published a package that allows to compile Rmd posts in Hakyll:
https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hakyll-R

Answer (score 0):

For the moment I write my blog post in Rmarkdown, and transform it in plain markdown with:

```
Rscript -e "library(knitr); knit('myPost.Rmd')
```

Then Hakyll can process it. More details here: http://www.corentindupont.info/blog/posts/Programming/2014-12-10-This-Blog.html.
I would be glad to know if this command can be integrated directly into Hakyll.